# Portable Ubuntu on USB flash drive or SD card

Tags: portable

I want to install a portable Ubuntu on either a USB flash drive or an SD card. I do not know which one is better. I am going to use it a lot. I think that in either case it is better for me to keep the drive/card plugged in. In this way, every time I need to use Ubuntu, I will not have to insert it and thus, I will avoid deterioration caused by continuous insertions/ejections. On the other hand, is it still a good idea to keep the drive/card plugged in all the time, even if I use Windows, not Ubuntu? I mean, is keeping it inserted also harmful for it? If yes, which one is less harmful: keeping it inserted or ejecting it after use?

I also need your help regarding the speed of the USB flash drive and SD card. Which one is recommended for my purposes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

USB flash drives can be faster than SD cards, but it's not a hard-and-fast rule. The drive's connector inside the metal sleeve gives a hint.

```
Red     USB3.1 Gen2 10,000 Mbps 
Blue    USB3.0       5,000 Mbps
Black   USB2.0         480 Mbps
White   USB1            12 Mbps
```

Of course, the connector on the PC also has to match, else you won't get that speed. The slower connection (on PC or flash drive) determines the maximum throughput.  Those are also theoretical maximum speeds.

Your card vendor provides the read and write speed on the package when you buy an SD or SDHC card. Here's a site which shows the [current fastest SDHC cards](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/fastest-sd-cards/). Also, a lot of older machines just won't boot from an SD card.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a new laptop which has both the card reader and USB 3.1 Gen2 port. Thus, I can purchase the fastest one. What do you think regarding my question about inserting/ejecting the drive/card all the time vs keeping it plugged in all the time?